# Audiobus : Migrating from sdk 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I am migrating from audiobus sdk 1.0 to 2.0 to support ios8. but I am facing some problem with functionality code.

**What I want to achieve**: my app is a receiver,I want to play received audio with ABReceiverPortReceive method.

In old sdk there is callback method in ABInputPort when audio available but in sdk 2.0 no callback method is there in ABReceiverPort

Following is my old code of sdk 1.0

```
_inputPort.audioInputBlock = ^(ABInputPort *inputPort, UInt32 lengthInFrames, AudioTimeStamp *nextTimestamp, ABPort *sourcePortOrNil) {

    // get samples from audiobus
    AudioBufferList* receiveBufferList = alloca(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (_receiveBufferList->mNumberBuffers - 1) * sizeof(AudioBuffer));
    memcpy(receiveBufferList, _receiveBufferList, sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (_receiveBufferList->mNumberBuffers - 1) * sizeof(AudioBuffer));

    ABInputPortReceive(inputPort, sourcePortOrNil, receiveBufferList, &lengthInFrames, nextTimestamp, NULL);

    // put samples into buffer
    if (lengthInFrames > 0)
    {
        ABMultiStreamBufferEnqueue([ABPlugin plugin].inputBuffer, sourcePortOrNil, receiveBufferList, lengthInFrames, nextTimestamp);
    }
};
```

here I call ABInputPortReceive when calback method called and audio available but no callback method in new sdk.

SO I called the ABReceiverPortReceive method in my audio engine callback method.

```
- (OSStatus)render:(AudioBufferList *)buffer frames:(NSUInteger)numFrames timestamp:(const AudioTimeStamp *)timestamp flags:(AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *)ioFlags
{

      // NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    if (nil == self.source)
    {
        *ioFlags |= kAudioUnitRenderAction_OutputIsSilence;
        return noErr;
    }

    // read previously enqueued by plugin samples from buffer into output buffer
    UInt32 totalFrames = 0;
    UInt32 framesFromBuffer = numFrames;

    // get samples from input buffer
    AudioBufferList* receiveBufferList = alloca(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (_receiveBufferList->mNumberBuffers - 1) * sizeof(AudioBuffer));
    memcpy(receiveBufferList, _receiveBufferList, sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (_receiveBufferList->mNumberBuffers - 1) * sizeof(AudioBuffer));

    AudioTimeStamp bufferTimestamp = *timestamp;
     ABMultiStreamBufferDequeueSingleSource([ABPlugin plugin].inputBuffer, self.source, receiveBufferList, &framesFromBuffer, &bufferTimestamp);
    totalFrames += framesFromBuffer;

    _framesPlayed += numFrames;
    [ABPlugin plugin].framesPlayed = MAX([ABPlugin plugin].framesPlayed, _framesPlayed);

    ABMultiStreamBufferMarkSourceIdle([ABPlugin plugin].inputBuffer, self.source);

    // convert AB format to output stream format
    OSStatus result = AudioConverterConvertComplexBuffer(_formatConverter, totalFrames, receiveBufferList, buffer);

    AudioTimeStamp timestamp1 = *timestamp;
    if ( ABReceiverPortIsConnected([ABPlugin plugin].inputPort) ) {
        // Receive audio from Audiobus
        ABReceiverPortReceive([ABPlugin plugin].inputPort, self.source, _receiveBufferList, numFrames, &timestamp1);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Problem : There is no audio recieved in this way

Please help or suggest something as early as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it correct to write:
    totalFrames += framesFromBuffer;
Instead of:
    totalFrames = totalFrames + framesFromBuffer;
Just a comment/question.

Comment: yes it is good....and no issue with that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are handling the multi stream here. may be you need to differentiate between the sources of sound. I can't help with the code.

Comment: well I check it.you got the points because this is better than other answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you see this website 1.x-2.x Migration Guide : http://developer.audiob.us/doc/_migration-_guide.html

Comment: yes I followed the documentation. and after that got this problem.